# Background image doesn't fit properly and add a shadow to button

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a student who's new to mobile app development. I designed the UX using adobe XD. And i exported the background from adobe XD to android studio as a png. I tried a few methods, but the image doesn't fit according to what i want. The image's width doesn't fully fit the width , so there's some white space in the width. and also the height of the image is larger than the device(The curve should be much higher so the 'dont' have an account' text is below that curve) [image]

This is how i want the page to look(This is from Adobe XD).
But this is how it looks.
[image]

Also i want to add a shadow to the Sign in button like in the design. It would be a big help.
here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tolo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bauh93"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:shadowColor="@color/white"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="8"
            android:text="TOLO"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="90dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/signin"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/signin"
            android:textColor="@color/teal"
            android:textSize="20dp"
 />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/signuptxt"
    android:text="Don't have an account?"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/signupbtn"
   android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/lblue"
    android:backgroundTint="#0000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use [elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping) for shadow and don't use static margins

Comment: i added elevation. but it didn't make any difference. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Your Relative Layout must be like this (add your picture as background attribute to Relative Layout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/bg">
```

then you no more need any other ImageView for background.

Comment: This solved the 'don't have an account?' text showing up on the correct place. but still there's white space(almost like a margin) around the image, on both width and height. I tried changing the size of the image. but it didn't work. In the adobe XD , i have made the images size as '375 x 667'.  is this  resolution wrong? Thanks by the way

Comment: don't you have any other parent layout?

Comment: no, i haven't add any other. will it work if i add another?

Comment: No, Actually it shouldn't be like that. I thought maybe there is another parent layout. I don't know what the problem is now.

Comment: Note that "fill_parent" is now deprecated, use "match_parent" instead.